# Custom android frame for camera

Tags: android

I want to have a default background/frame for my android camera. Basically something which allows me to put a picture taken from camera inside a custom frame. Anyone has any idea as how to do this please

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the frame capture mode.

You will need to get hold of a frame with a hole, like an astronaut floating in the space but the his is cut out..

Once you have this frame you need to overlay this image (`ImageView`) ontop of the preview (`SurfaceView`) . The user will align it and take a picture.

You have to be careful now, if the captured image is bigger in resolution than the preview then you will have to perform x and y translation to get it correctly in place.

Then you just blend the two images and voila you have captured an image within a frame!